# jquery - change div based on selection - works only on fiddle

Tags: jquery, select

I'm trying to help my polish friend with his website - I think there is a kind of mess with jquery code done by previous developer (which is a totally different matter). He asked me to add one more functionality - changing div content based on select option. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pa-kategoria_cenowa").change(function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="5"){
            $(".box").not(".5").hide();
            $(".5").show();
        }
        else if($(this).attr("value")=="10"){
            $(".box").not(".10").hide();
            $(".10").show();
        }
        else if($(this).attr("value")=="15"){
            $(".box").not(".15").hide();
            $(".15").show();
        }
        else{
            $(".box").hide();
        }
    });
}).change();
```

});

and the jsfiddle itself: https://jsfiddle.net/bgksk5Le/

The issue is weird though - this code works on the jsfiddle, but on the website - not. This is the url: http://bookszop.com/www/produkt/hilary-mantel-bring-up-the-bodies/

everything is linked to the dropdown menu with a caption KATEGORIA CENOWA. Unfortunatelly - that jquery code seems not to affect any piece of the website (as you see, DIV with descriptions are visible; in fact they should be hidden at start)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: general-scripts.js causing issue with Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined. Look into it and you may get solution.

Comment: There is no element on the page named 'pr-kategoria_cenowa` so the `.change()` event certainly won't ever run.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple <select id="pa_kategoria-cenowa" name="attribute_pa_kategoria-cenowa">...</select>

Comment: even removing code which generates that error - my issue still exists. So its not that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
$("#pa-kategoria_cenowa").change(function(){
```

But in fact that should be:

```
$("#pa_kategoria-cenowa").change(function(){
```

The underscores and hyphens are just switched around there. There was no element on the page with the exact ID you were using.

Comment: thanks, I've fixed that. Unfortunatelly it doesn't fix the issue;/

Comment: What's supposed to be showing or hiding? I don't see anything with `.box` or `.5` or `.15` on the page either.

Comment: it is - just under the select field there are lines like: Wybierz cenę korzystając z rozwijanego pola
CENA 5 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper egestas sodales. In commodo massa eget lectus eleifend, nec dictum sapien laoreet. They have such classes